# Combine multiple `Collectors::groupBy` functions with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a problem with correctly combining multiple `Collectors::groupingBy` functions and then applying them all at once to a given input.

Let's say I have some class implementing following interface:

```
interface Something {
    String get1();
    String get2();
    String get3();
    String get4();
}
```

And now I can have some list of combinations of the methods from this interface, i.e. these lists can be:
`[Something::get1, Something::get3]`, `[Something::get2, Something::get1, Something::get3]`.

Now, having such a list of methods and having a list of somethings, I would like to group those somethings by getters.

What I mean is  that for example for the list `[Something::get1, Something::get3]` and a list `[Something1, Something2, ...]` I want to get the list of somethings grouped firstly by `get1` and then by `get2`.

This can be achieved this way:

```
var lst = List.of(smth1, smth2, smth3);
lst.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Something::get1, Collectors.groupingBy(Something::get3)))
```

What if I have any arbitrary list of methods that I would like to apply to grouping?

I was thinking of something like this (ofc. this does not work, but you will get the idea):

Assume that `List<Function<Something, String>> groupingFunctions` is our list of methods we want to apply to grouping.

```
var collector = groupingFunctions.stream()
                                 .reduce((f1, f2) -> Collectors.groupingBy(f1, Collectors.groupingBy(f2)))
```

and then

```
List.of(smth1, smth2, smth3).stream().collect(collector)
```

But this approach does not work. How to achieve the result I am thinking of?

Comment: How does the final result look like?

Comment: Final result is a nested map.

Comment: The final `Map` key-value type is 4 nested, can you raw type?

Comment: How would you use the result, when you don’t know its type?

Comment: @Holger - if Something would have a property `List<Something> children` and a property `String name`, I would re-map the maps to a Something object, where the key would be the name and the list would be children, so that would be no problem. I just wanted to have a generic solution to create a deeply nested tree-like structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static Collector createCollector(Function<A, String>... groupKeys) {
    Collector collector = Collectors.toList();
    for (int i = groupKeys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        collector = Collectors.groupingBy(groupKeys[i], collector);
    }
    return collector;
}
```

This give you a raw collector, hence your stream result after grouping is also raw.

```
Collector collector = createCollector(Something::get1, Something::get2);
```

You can use this `collector` like this:

```
Object result = somethingList.stream().collect(collector);
```

Because you know how many `groupingBy` you passed to the collector, you can cast it to appropriate `Map` result. In this case two `groupingBy` is applied:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Something>>> mapResult = (Map<String, Map<String, List<Something>>>) result
```

Comment: Actually, I can't cast it because I do not have any a priori knowledge about how many groupingBy will be applied. It can be 1, 2, 5 or any other number of groupings. 

Also, I would like to stick to the functional approach, that's why I mentioned reduce. I know that I could loop over the list of functions, but I don't want to do this.

Comment: You can refactor the `createCollector` using the `functional` way. But nothing can solve the `cast` part. in the end you still need to know the type of `Map` for casting

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t know how many functions are in the list, you can’t declare a compile-time type reflecting the nesting. But even when using a collector type producing some unknown result type, composing it is not solvable in the clean functional way you intend. The closest you can get is

```
var collector = groupingFunctions.stream()
    .<Collector<Something,?,?>>reduce(
        Collectors.toList(),
        (c,f) -> Collectors.groupingBy(f, c),
        (c1,c2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("can't handle that"); });
```

which has two fundamental problems. There is no way to provide a valid merge function for two `Collector` instances, so while this may work with a sequential operation, it is not a clean solution. Further, the nesting of the result maps will be in the opposite order; the last function of the list will provide the keys to the outermost map.

There might be ways to fix that, but all of them will make the code even more complicated. Compare this with a straight-forward loop:

```
Collector<Something,?,?> collector = Collectors.toList();
for(var i = groupingFunctions.listIterator(groupingFunctions.size()); i.hasPrevious(); )
    collector = Collectors.groupingBy(i.previous(), collector);
```

You can use the collector like

```
Object o = lst.stream().collect(collector);
```

but need `instanceof` and type casts to process the `Map`s…

It would be cleaner to create a single, non-nested `Map` with `List` keys which reflect the grouping functions:

```
Map<List<String>,List<Something>> map = lst.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    o -> groupingFunctions.stream().map(f -> f.apply(o))
                          .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())));
```

It would allow querying entries like `map.get(List.of(arguments, matching, grouping, functions))`